# WPF polygons disappearing, flickering, Z-fighting?

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon

I am working with a 3D-WPF Application that contains very larg as well as tiny 3D-Objects at the same time. (a satellite simulation)

To display them at the same time I have to set the NearPlaneDistance to a much lower value than the FarPlaneDistance (factor 10^9 times smaller), which seems to be the root of the problem

Now I have the problem that some polygons disappear (e.g are not drawn) at certain camera settings ( look direction etc. ) -> When the camera moves it flickers. ([Example Picture of an MWE i coded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLEu8.png)  just one really big cube and and a very small one)

I suspect this is caused by [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting), but I am not sure because sometimes whole objects disappear, and there is also a big difference between objects *ModelVisual3D*s that have been transformed or not.

I tried various combinations of Near and FarPlaneDistances but there is always some problems.

Is there a way to increase the z-Buffer precision or make it logarithmic ?

I know Wikipedia suggest cheating about the distance (making an object smaller to simulate distance), but i thought before getting into that I ask here :)

Comment: It certainly sounds like it could be a z-fighting issue, but with the added complication that your near and far planes are so far apart. I suspect that you're not going to be able to increase the z-buffer precision. The other solution is to break up your large triangles into smaller ones so that all the triangles in the scene are more or less the same size.

Comment: What do you mean by more or less the same size ? Because to be equal size the planet would need to be made of about 5*10^18 polygons.

Comment: That is the drawback with doing that :) You could make the planet polygons smaller, but not that small. It will reduce but not eliminate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably z-fighting due to floating point rounding error at those high sizes.  The larger the floating point numbers get, the more their accuracy decreases.

You could try scaling everything down by an order of magnitude to get more floating point accuracy.  This shouldn't affect your simulation or anything visual as long as you scale everything down equally to match, such as cameras, positions, and entity movement.

Comment: I tried scaling everything down or up by 1,2,3 orders of magnitude but it did not make any difference.